# How to remove pair of small and capital letters in a string?

Tags: python

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a code that removes a pair of lower and capital letters. e.g. :

```
AbBax -» x
cCdatabasacCADde -» database
```

I've tried doing this but it gives me an error, maybe my train of thought is wrong.

```
def decode(c_p):
    t_cp=[]
    for i in c_p:
        t_cp+=[I,]
#here I added each character from the string to a list so it would be easier to analyse each character
    new_c_p=""
    for c in range(len(t_cp)-1):
        if not t_cp[c]==chr(ord(c)) and t_cp[c+1]==chr(ord(c) + 32) or  not t_cp[c]==chr(ord(c) + 32) and t_cp[c+1]==chr(ord(c)) :
#here I analyse the index c and c+1 to know if the first character corresponds to the next in capital or vice-versa, if doesn't correspond, I add that character into new_c_p 
            new_c_p+=c
    return new_c_p
```

Comment: Your train of thought would be easier to follow if you described it in words also

Comment: I would expect `cCdatabasacCADde` to become databasae?

Comment: @rv.kvetch After the `cC` is out, you can remove the `aA` for `database`, I guess.

Comment: no because I'm trying to eliminate the same characters but in different sizes, so "aA" gets eliminated but "Aa" also gets eliminated

Comment: @user2390182 ooohhh, gotcha. So you're actually modifying the indices and the string itself, on each iteration of the string. Interesting, I didn't think about it like that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly simpler approach:

```
def decode(c_p):
    while True:
        for i, pair in enumerate(zip(c_p, c_p[1:])):
            up, lo = sorted(pair)
            if up.lower() == lo and up == lo.upper():
                c_p = c_p[:i] + c_p[i+2:]
                break
        else: 
            return c_p

decode("cCdatabasacCADde")
# 'database'
```

And here is an even better one that does not start all the way from the beginning every time and has actually linear time and space complexity:

```
def decode(c_p):
    stack = []
    for c in c_p:
        if not stack:
            stack.append(c)
        else:
            up, lo = sorted((stack[-1], c))          
            if up.lower() == lo and lo.upper() == up:
                stack.pop()
            else:
                stack.append(c)
    return "".join(stack)
```